# Авторизация через социальные сети используя WebView

Tags: android, auth

Есть [библиотека](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE).
Она хороша, но не всегда возвращает `email`, например, из Twittera и VK `email` всегда `null`.

Есть библиотека или иной быстрый способ реализовать вебовскую авторизовалку в `WebView`, по результатам которой будут возвращаться данные из авторизованной социальной сети?

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть 2 очень хороших библиотек для этого. Вот:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3987

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4519

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ,  дать  только ссылки недостаточно.

Comment: "Есть библиотека" eto vaw vopros, tut ne skazano chto nujno step-by-step instrukcii

Comment: to chto vy govorite eto uje drugoy vopros